# Using free() on a pointer within a struct frees memory for the entire struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, free

I have two `struct`s within my program. The first one, `huffchar` is below, and just shows the general structure (mostly irrelevant to the question), but the second one, `huffcoder` is the one that I'm having an issue with:

```
struct huffchar {   
    int freq;   
    int is_compound;   
    int seqno;   
    union {
        struct {
        struct huffchar * left;
        struct huffchar * right;
        } compound;
        unsigned char c;   
    } u; 
};


struct huffcoder {   
    int freqs[NUM_CHARS];
    int code_lengths[NUM_CHARS];
    unsigned long long codes[NUM_CHARS];
    struct huffchar * tree;
    int sizeOfTree; 
};
```

When I initialize a `huffcoder` in my program, I malloc `ourHuffCoder` the size of a `huffcoder`, and then malloc memory for X many elements to the `struct huffchar * tree`:

`struct huffcoder * ourHuffChar = malloc(sizeof(struct huffcoder));`

`ourHuffChar -> tree = malloc(sizeof(struct huffchar)*NUM_CHARS);`

However, I will need to make this tree larger at a later point, and do not know how many elements will be on this tree at the end. In other words, every time I add an element, I will create a new tree with `realloc()` that is one element larger, then set the pointer for `tree` within the `huffcoder` to this new `updatedTree`.

The follow lines of code are intended to achieve this:

```
    struct huffchar * updatedTree = realloc(ourHuffCoder -> tree, (ourHuffCoder->sizeOfTree+1)*sizeof(struct huffchar));
    free(ourHuffCoder -> tree);
    ourHuffCoder -> tree = updatedTree;
```

Note that I use the line `free(ourHuffCoder -> tree)` to free the memory that has been previously allocated to the tree, before updating the `tree` pointer to `updatedTree`. However, when I reach the `free(ourHuffCoder -> tree)` line, memory allocated to the **entirety** of the HuffCoder pointer `ourHuffCoder` is freed instead of just the memory allocated to the `tree`.

Here is my variables window **before** running the `free(ourHuffCoder->tree)` line:
[image]

And here is **after** running the `free(ourHuffCoder->tree)` line:
[image]

I have also tried creating an entirely new pointer `huffchar * ourTree = ourHuffCoder -> tree` and use this variable for the `free()` method instead, but I get the same result.

Just to test my code, I modified the above code to remove the `free()` line,

```
    struct huffchar * updatedTree = realloc(ourHuffCoder -> tree, (ourHuffCoder->sizeOfTree+1)*sizeof(struct huffchar));
    ourHuffCoder -> tree = updatedTree;
```

This is obviously not what I should be doing because I will run out of memory quickly, but I wanted to see if the pointer to `tree` within `huffcoder` would be updated to point to `updatedTree`, which is has:

Before `ourHuffCoder -> tree = updatedTree;`
[image]

After `ourHuffCoder -> tree = updatedTree;`
[image]

My question is, why is the memory allocated to the entirety of the `huffcoder` struct being freed, instead of just the memory to the `tree`? How do I solve this? Is there a better way of increasing the memory allocated to the `tree`?

Comment: Are you freeing a pointer to the first element of a struct, which of course shares the address with the whole struct? A) You cannot free parts. B) How do you expect the system to tell apart whether you want to free all or only the first? C) Did you try freeing a later member of the struct?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc "The reallocation is done by...allocating a new memory block..., copying memory area..., and freeing the old block."  So you don't want to free it because double freeing memory causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake I see is that `realloc` is already a combination of `malloc` and `free`. The `free` call here is unnecessary and wrong:

```
struct huffchar * updatedTree = realloc(ourHuffCoder -> tree, (ourHuffCoder->sizeOfTree+1)*sizeof(struct huffchar));
free(ourHuffCoder -> tree);
ourHuffCoder -> tree = updatedTree;
```

That is to say, when we call `realloc(ptr)`, `ptr` is deallocated and a new pointer is returned. The allocator can sometimes optimize the process by resizing the old object in place.

There is no need to free `ptr`, and we must not do so, in fact.

If we didn't care about the optimization, we could almost write `realloc` like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) : (a) : (b))

void *our_realloc(void *oldptr, size_t newsize)
{
   if (newsize == 0) {
      free(oldptr);
      return 0;
   } else {
      void *newptr = malloc(newsize);
      if (oldptr) {
         size_t oldsize = __obtain_old_size_in_nonportable_way(oldptr);
         memcpy(newptr, oldptr, min(oldsize, newsize));
         free(oldptr); // !!!!
      }
      return newptr;
   }
}
```

Even in cases when `realloc` returns the "same" pointer, the program cannot easily tell. The old pointer has become invalid, so any use of it is undefined behavior:

```
newptr = realloc(oldptr, size);

if (newptr == oldptr) {  // did it really move?
```

The use of `oldptr` here is technically undefined behavior.  We never hold the two pointers simultaneously; we have traded one for the other and the transaction took place inside the `realloc` blackbox.

We can capture a printed image:

```
char oldptr_txt[64], newptr_txt[64];
snprintf(oldptr_txt, sizeof oldptr_txt, "%p", (void *) oldptr);
newptr = realloc(oldptr, size);
snprintf(newptr_txt, sizeof newptr_txt, "%p", (void *) newptr);

if (strcmp(oldptr_txt, newptr_txt) == 0) {
  // almost certainly stayed in place
} else {
  // almost certainly moved
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is undefined beahviour to compare the two pointers; aren't they just compared as integer-valued memory addresses? When you pass `oldptr` to `realloc()`, it is passed by value; the contents pointed at are potentially copied to a new address (returned intop `newptr`), the beginning of a contiguous region of the required size. But the _value_ of the pointer oldptr` (i.e., the old address), not the pointed-at object, should be unchanged, right? Why is it undefined to compare the _value_ of the (invalid) old pointer and the new one? What am I missing?

Comment: @NicolasMiari It works fine on every compiler I've used, but ISO C says that when memory is freed, the pointer becomes indeterminate. Use of an indeterminate value is undefined behavior.